# PhoneGap App rejected 10.6

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store, phonegap-plugins

Our PhoneGap App just got rejected.

Binary Rejected:

> 10.6: Apple and our customers place a high value on simple, refined, creative, well thought through interfaces. They take more work but are
>   worth it. Apple sets a high bar. If your user interface is complex or
>   less than very good it may be rejected

Text:

> "We found the following issues with the user interface of your app:
>
> - Did not include iOS features. For example, it would be appropriate to use native iOS buttons and iOS features other than just web views,
>     Push Notifications, or sharing.
>
> Specifically, we noticed the app provides a consumption of information
>   with limited ways users can interact with that information. It would
>   be appropriate to add iOS specific UI and functionality rather than
>   displaying just text and table views."

On above they are first referring to the interface and the look and next they are reffering to just the content/function and that the app just provides informations.

The Interface is clean and simple.
**It is an application that provides (premium) informations. There are several apps in app store who work like this.**

I heard about including some plugin or API so that I can justify the App. But there would be no sense in this app for the use of an plugin. Or has someone an Idea to provide fake functions?

Would be sad if we couldn't release this app, we put a lot of time and effort in this app.

Has anyone tips on how to submit an information-based application?

Comment: @0x7fffffff Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately for legal reasons I can not provide an screenshot. But it is still very basic: Header (just title), content (contains on every tab smiliar divs with different text, footer (contains 4 clean tabs)

Comment: Are the tabs native tab bar or html?  Depend on the reviewer, and since native does have a tab functionality, sometime they can be picky and want you to use native.

Comment: @Noogen Not native. Everything build with PhoneGap + Jquery Mobile. We modified it in color and shadows, it looks alike the standart JQM navbar, but there are a lot of Apps on the Appstore which use the JQM navbar.

Comment: @RedErdnuss I am facing same problem, I am not comfortable to upload in IOS store. There is any other alternate solution, to share my app to my clients. One way is should publish my app in my own website but i could not track the number of downloads. So could you suggest any other third party sites.

Answer (score 3):

It's highly likely that Apple rejected the app due to it being just a website wrapped in Phonegap.  They do this as they expect you to make some use of the OS.  Bear in mind when they look at your App they statically analyse it and it will show what APIs you are using, if you are using none, it will be rejected.  In this case, perhaps the best way is to develop it as a HTML5 app using use the features of iOS to make it feel like an app - caching for example.

Otherwise, I'd make it look very much like an app.  I've developed an app for my workplace, and whilst using a number of APIs such as location, and push notifications, no user would ever know it's developed using Phonegap.  Have a look here:

https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/chester/id665701380?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

You do need an account to make it work, but the screenshots will give you an example of the sort of UI Apple would expect.  It doesn't have to look like a iOS app - I've used a Windows Phone-like interface, but I have retained the back button at the top left, and styled it to look like iOS7.

You can find a useful resource here:

http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-7-design-cheat-sheet/

This gives you dimensions and clues to what iOS colours, fonts, icons etc to use.

You can get Glyphish icons (http://www.glyphish.com) to add to the quality of the app, and remember they expect retina images also now.

Use Phonegap 2.7 or above to make sure it's fully compliant with the retina requirements.

Comment: Interesting... your app looks much less like an iOS App. On the Login-Page even page dragging isn't disabled. We put our main focus on design and layout since this is an informational app there was really not much else to focus on. We also used retina icons and stuff. And it looks good, except that we did not use back btns(changed). So it is about the device APIs, we use none of them. **Do you think it would be enough to include&use the PhoneGap Network/Connection API and/or the Events API(deviceready,online,offline) and/or Notification API to get the app approved?** Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You'll definitely need to use at least deviceready as good practice with Phonegap anyway.  If you're app is just content, then Apple will likely always reject it - they'd direct you to using a mobile website.  However, because of the nature of how they analyse the app, I'd recommend you use network APIs for on/offline at least.

I haven't disabled page scrolling on the login page as it's cross platform and needs to support much smaller screens on Android.  I keep my code identical across platforms.  Otherwise it *is* disabled so the back button/page title stays at the top.

Comment: Where did you hear they do a static analysis? Because it is usually performed on source code, something Apple does not get from developers. But for the second part you are probably right, they do check which API's are you calling.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question on stackoverflow while searching to the same on iOS 7. I had similar problem way beck with iOS 6 and the problem was resolved. Answer is here http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/ios_app_rejected_advice_on_how_to_fix_it

I'm not sure if the answer will apply to iOS 7 since Apple deprecated the tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your apps' look and feel (UI/UX) does not conform to the iOS, which means they may not look at all like ios apps. You need to provide navigation like iphone apps (with back button on top), bottom nav bar (if possible).

Also use some phone specific features - like getting location (which obviously could be very useful info).

Basically the app should not be a wrapper for a webapp which can be used directly from the browser.

Comment: see this link too - http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/10/03/phonegap-apple-rejections-uiux-guidelines/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We tried to keep the look very simple and professional. But... regarding the back-button: we did not know that and didn't include them, ..although we navigate to different views with the divs... we are gonna change that among other things. Thanks.                                               The phone specific features are not useful for our application, I have no Idea at what part we could include a plugin. :/